# How to find if an XSD element is required using MOXy Dynamic JAXB?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, moxy

I'm trying to get information out of an XSD using MOXy's DynamicJAXBContext. One of the properties I'm trying to get is if an attribute or element is **required**. From what I understand, if an element has `minOccurs="1"` it means it is **required**.

The issue is that I haven't found a way to get this.

Here's the code I have until now:

```
DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext = 
                DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(is, new MyEntityResolver(), null, null);


        Collection<ClassDescriptor> descriptors = jaxbContext.getXMLContext().getSession().getDescriptors().values();
        for (ClassDescriptor desc : descriptors) {
            if (desc.getJavaClassName() != null) {
                System.out.println("=================================");
                System.out.println("Class: " + desc.getJavaClassName());
                desc.getMappings().forEach(dm ->{
                    System.out.println(dm.getAttributeName());

                    System.out.println(dm.getClass().getName());
                    if(dm instanceof XMLDirectMapping) {
                        XMLDirectMapping xmlInfo = (XMLDirectMapping)dm;
                        System.out.println(xmlInfo);
                    }
                    if(dm.getAttributeClassification() != null) {
                        System.out.println(dm.getAttributeClassification().getName());
                    }
                    if(dm.getReferenceDescriptor() != null) {
                        System.out.println(dm.getReferenceDescriptor().getJavaClassName());
                    }
                 });

            }
        }
```

Until now, I have been able to get information regarding the attribute type, if it's a collection and the collection type.

I've tried exploring other methods of the `dm` variable including `isOptional()` and `getField().isNullable()` and both return `true` for attributes where `minOccurs="1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the object returned by the `getField()` is actually of type `XMLField` which is a subclass of the general type returned by that method `DatabaseField`. The `XMLField` has an `isRequired()` method that effectively returns if the attribute is required.

```
 if(dm.getField() instanceof XMLField) {
     XMLField field = (XMLField)dm.getField();
     System.out.println(field.isRequired());
 }
```